# how to create even spacing in navbar

Tags: css, html

I was wondering how I could create even spacing in my navbar. I want to have even spacing between the "History, Etymology, and About." I also want that part to stay on the right, while the Shiba Inu stays on the left.  I have attached a picture of what I have currently and also a picture of what I would like.

Thank you!

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajSAl.png)

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeJ4H.png)

```css
.navbar{
    font-size: 13pt;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    height: 70px;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
}

.main-nav{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 30px;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.home, 
.nav-links{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#212020;
}

.main-nav li{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin: 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 13pt;
}

.home{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
        <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="index.html" class="home">SHIBA INU</a>
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html" class="nav-links" >ABOUT</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-links" >ETYMOLOGY</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-links" >HISTORY</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary:

- Make sure your flex parent or flex container have a width
  defined of the parent in this case 100% means the full window as
  there is no other parent here.
- On the other hand the space between elements of the list can be done
  with multiple approaches but I think a margin that excludes the last
  one should work for your use case.

```css
.navbar{
    font-size: 13pt;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    height: 70px;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-nav{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 30px;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-grow: 1;
    align-items: justify-content;
}

.home, 
.nav-links{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#212020;
}

.main-nav li{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin: 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 13pt;
}

   .main-nav li:not(:last-child) {
   margin-right: 10px;
   }

.home{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
        <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="index.html" class="home">SHIBA INU</a>
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html" class="nav-links" >ABOUT</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-links" >ETYMOLOGY</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-links" >HISTORY</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```